# how do i locate files in wordpress by inspecting element a particular element in google chrome?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to change some particular line on my Wordpress site which I cannot change in the customization. How do I locate a certain line with inspect element in chrome?

My website is www.Artiana.io and I want to edit this line:

```html
"<h5 class="subscribe-description">Learn more</h5>"
```

Please, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you how you can use WordPress's hints in html body class to find the php file:

WordPress gives hint in the HTML's body tag that which particular template was used to display this page.

In your case we have following classes in the body tag:

```
<body class="home page-template page-template-page-templates page-template-page_front-page page-template-page-templatespage_front-page-php page page-id-466 custom-background wp-custom-logo blog-post">
```

Now there is a specific class which ends with php, which tells that template was used by your theme to build this page. i.e. `page-template-page-templatespage_front-page-php`

Now it could mean that in your theme folder:

> /wp-content/themes/hestia/

There could be sub folder or folders called: `**page-template/page-templates**` and inside it is **`page_front-page.php`** PHP file, which is being used to create this layout. See if you can locate the code you are trying to modify there.

Comment: I found the folder "page templates" but in it, there is a php file named "template-fullwidth.php", but I cannot find the code in that file.

Comment: @S.punk in your theme folder i.e. Hestia , can you do directory search and search for "front-page.php" you might find it somewhere.

Comment: I tried and searched it and found the file but I cannot find the code which I need to change